# Why smartphones have HD screens and 640px max width is applied

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have LG G2 smartphone with resolution 1920x1080. I created max-width conditional css styles and a 640px one is loaded when browsing in horizontal and 320 when vertical. What is going on? Is that normal? How to apply styles to smartphones with hd display?

Comment: How on earth should we know if you don't show us your conditional statements?

Comment: Think about it.  Desktop screens are running at 1920x1080.  If your media query targets that 1920 width, then you will affect both desktops and mobile phones.  However, it's not that simple (which is good!).  Pixel ratio means for every 2 pixels on the phone theres only 1 in your calculations.  There are other things that are device specific that adjust this farther down too.  Do a google search for mobile phone media queries and you'll find example of the media queries you should be using to target particular sized screens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because mobile browsers often render at a fraction of the screen resolution. They may be using  480x270, which can be confirmed with a `window.height` and `window.width`.

You *can* use js to target individual devices, but with the number of devices in the wild, this isn't a good idea. A better idea is to also target devices by resolution: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#resolution

Answer (score 1):

Because smartphones combine multiple physical pixels and display it as one digital pixel. This is why 2x images will appear much sharper than non.